# how to make a system in python that support limited users? for instance, it should support 200 users

Tags: python

How to Limit the amount of user registration? a system that should support a limited amount of users? how can we do that? please someone suggest a tutorial, website, or any good source.

I try to search about it but I couldn't find any useful thing on the internet

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information you provided is little insufficient, but do you mean check of registered user before new registration?

Something like this?

```python
def check_max_users(db_connection):
  users_count = db_connection.query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS users_count FROM users").first().users_count
  if users_count > 200:
    raise MaxUsersError()
```